# Load a point layer from CSV in PyQGIS QGIS 3.10

Tags: csv, vector, gis, qgis, pyqgis

I'm trying to use a script that loads in a point layer from CSV. The code that I used is:

`uri = "file:///some_path/PyQGIS/Some.csv?delimiter={}&xField={}&yField={}".format(os.getcwd(), ";", "X", "Y")`

`vlayer = QgsVectorLayer(uri, "Name", "delimitedtext")`

`QgsProject.instance().addMapLayer(vlayer)`

The structure of the .csv file is as follows:
SomeValue ----- X ----- Y

Hereby, the coordinates are put according to Amersfoort (EPSG:4289) e.g.: X = 213404, Y = 500846. When trying to load this in manually, everything is going fine. However in the script, it does not seem to work. To clarify: The delimiter used is a ;

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can specify the [projection of your data set](https://docs.qgis.org/3.10/en/docs/pyqgis_developer_cookbook/loadlayer.html) by adding `&crs=epsg:4723` to the URI definition. So your case becomes:

```
uri = "file:///some_path/PyQGIS/Some.csv?delimiter={}&crs=epsg:4289&xField={}&yField={}".format(os.getcwd(), ";", "X", "Y")

vlayer = QgsVectorLayer(uri, "Name", "delimitedtext")

QgsProject.instance().addMapLayer(vlayer)
```

Answer (score 0):

The answer to this is issue has been solved by removing the "os.getcwd()" part of the code. Hope this will help anyone with similar issues.